# Login with GXT3 MPV Request Factory

Tags: gwt, mvp, gxt, requestfactory

I have a project with sencha gxt 3, and I do not know how to do authentication (Login)

Please you, if you can help me with some examples.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at spring security.
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/12/securing-gwt-apps-with-spring-security.html#

1. For authentication what you need is a login form.
2. Secure the transmission with SSL.
3. Send credentials to server.
4. Encrypt password with some hashing algorithm.
5. Save credentials in some form of database.

   - http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html
   - http://jerryorr.blogspot.ie/2012/05/secure-password-storage-lots-of-donts.html#example

Consider using MVP pattern.As in MVP flow changes from one view to another view, it makes it easy to restrict user access to specific parts of website without any proper authority.